# THREEJS: Rotating the camera while lookingAt

Tags: camera, rotation, three.js

I have a moving camera in camera container which flies arond the scene on giving paths like an airplane; so it can move to any position x,y,z positive and negative. The camera container is looking at his own future path using a spline curve.

Now I want to rotate the camera using the mouse direction but still keeping the general looking at position while moving forward with object. You could say, i want to turn my head on my body: while moving the body having the general looking at direction, i am turning my head around to lets say 220 degree up and down. So i can't look behind my body.

In my code the cameraContainer is responsible to move on a pline curve and to lookAt the moving direction. The camera is added as a child to the cameraContainer responsible for the rotation using the mouse.

What i don't get working properly is the rotation of the camera. I guess its a very common problem. Lets say the camera when moving only on x-axes moves not straight, it moves like a curve. Specially in different camera positions, the rotation seems very different. I was tryiing to use the cameraContainer to avoid this problem, but the problem seems nothing related to the world coordinates.

Here is what i have:

```
// camera is in a container
cameraContainer = new THREEJS.Object3D();
cameraContainer.add(camera);
camera.lookAt(0,0,1);
cameraContainer.lookAt(nextPositionOnSplineCurve);


// Here goes the rotation depending on mouse
// Vertical
var mouseVerti = 1;     // 1 = top, -1 = bottom
if(window.App4D.mouse.y <= instance.domCenterPos.y)             // mouse is bottom?
    mouseVerti = -1;

// how far is the mouse away from center: 1 most, 0 near
var yMousePerc = Math.abs(Math.ceil((instance.domCenterPos.y - window.App4D.mouse.y) / (instance.domCenterPos.y - instance.domBoundingBox.bottom) * 100) / 100);
var yAngleDiffSide = (instance.config.scene.camera.maxAngle - instance.config.scene.camera.angle) / 2;
var yRotateRan = mouseVerti * yAngleDiffSide * yMousePerc * Math.PI / 180;
instance.camera.rotation.x += yRotateRan;       // rotation x = vertical


// Horizontal
var mouseHori = 1;      // 1 = top, -1 = bottom
if(window.App4D.mouse.x <= instance.domCenterPos.x)             // mouse is left?
    mouseHori = -1;

// how far is the mouse away from center: 1 most, 0 near
var xMousePerc = Math.abs(Math.ceil((instance.domCenterPos.x - window.App4D.mouse.x) / (instance.domCenterPos.x - instance.domBoundingBox.right) * 100) / 100);
var xAngleDiffSide = (instance.config.scene.camera.maxAngle - instance.config.scene.camera.angle) / 2;
var xRotateRan = mouseHori * xAngleDiffSide * xMousePerc * Math.PI / 180;
instance.camera.rotation.y += xRotateRan;       // rotation y = horizontal
```

Would be really thankful if someone can give me a hint!

Comment: I bet the problem is you just don't understand how Euler angles work. Try this: `camera.eulerOrder = "YXZ"`. This will be much more intuitive to you. And don't _increment_ the rotation based on the mouse coord, _assign_ the rotation based on the mouse coord. Keep the container fixed until you understand how the camera rotation works.

Comment: Thanks wesley for pointing me to euler angles. Indeed it wasn't clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer after some more trial and error. The solution is to simply take the initial rotation of y in consideration.

When setting up the camera container and the real camera as child of the container, i had to point the camera to the frontface of the camera container object, in order to let the camera looking in the right direction. That lead to the initial rotation of 0, 3.14, 0 (x,y,z). The solution was to added 3.14 to the y rotation everytime i assigned (as mentioned by WestLangley) the mouse rotation.

```
cameraReal.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1));
cameraReal.rotation.y = xRotateRan + 3.14;
```